# created node id in the next form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a content type which is created using CCK's(Establishment). I have used $form['#redirect'] to redirect the user to another form that is generated from a custom module(Beers). My requirement is i need to save the created Establishment node id with values of beers module. How can i do this?

Comment: You can pass a variable in the link/redirect and then take the variable in the link and save it in the (beer)form. This is not a secure way, because the user could change the Node_id that is in the link.

Comment: the problem in this case is i have $form['#redirect']='node/add/bears'; in the hook_form_alter how can i get the node id for the node that is not at created in the hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and in admin/rules/trigger/add  i created new rule and and added rule element as IFconditionCreated (content is Content Type) DO page redirect and in page redirect i set To as node/add/bears and in the next text box i added below code.

n_id=nid; ?>

Everything worked Great.